# Listviews switch places

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, windows-7, tablelayoutpanel

I have a winforms `UserControl` (UC) with a `TableLayoutPanel` (TLP). This panel has 2 columns and 1 row and is docked to fill the whole UC. Inside each column in the TLP I have a `GroupBox`, which is also set to `dock.Fill`. Last I have a `ListView` inside each group box which is also docked to fill.

I have list view A in the left column and list view B in the right column. I have tested my application on several computers without any problems. But on one computer list views get switched, so they are displayed: B | A instead of A | B

Does anybody have an idea to what could be causing this.

I apologize if the explanation is fuzzy or this is some trivial thing, I just never experienced this before.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if the computer in question is x64 and the other ones are x86

Comment: And one more thing - set both columns on TLP to 100% if not done so, and see what happens

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for the late reply. I have tried what you suggested. Setting both Columns to 100% just revert them back to 50% each, when you close the edit window. The hardware architecture on both machines are exactly the same. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Just go over each and every control, and make sure that all have Dock = Fill. And, may be, try to set this up from the beginning. I had this kind thing couple of times- you work on control and suddenly, you move something and it doesn't work well. Then, no matter what you do, it just doesn't work well. Start over, and it suddenly works. Who knows? VS IDE also has bugs

Comment: Also, monitor this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189352/windows-forms-re-arranging-elements-in-table-layout-panel

Comment: @DavidWakeman I am facing the exact same problem man. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @DavidWakeman: IDEA - in your `GroupBox` set `Docking = None` and set all 4 anchors in Anchor property. Use `padding` to clear borders. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171691%28v=vs.90%29.aspx something is different about TLP - "In other container controls, the child control is not resized when the Anchor property is set to Left, Right or Top, Bottom". Basically, instead of Fill, set Anchors on the control, which sits directly on TLP - try

Comment: @T.S I think the link you sent might be the solution. The designer assigned both groupboxes to the same tablelayoutpanel column like the post. I added a column and moved one of the groupboxes outside and back in. Now the designer look correct. I can't tell if this solved the problem until I do a new release (since me computer didn't have the problem). But I will keep you informed. Thank you so far.

Comment: @Raghavendra Kumar Try checking out the link T.S provided, and see if the designer is arranging your elements in the same column.

Comment: @DavidWakeman David, I found out the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189352/windows-forms-re-arranging-elements-in-table-layout-panel

Comment: @T.S: It is working. It was definitely the auto generated code in the designer like you suggested. You should post it as a solution. Cheers.

Comment: @DavidWakeman Which solution helped you, redo the control?

Comment: @T.S: This one: "Also, monitor this [Win-forms re-arranging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189352/windows-forms-re-arranging-elements-in-table-layout-panel) –  T.S. Jan 17 at 15:41"

Answer (score 0):

Try make form property `RightToLeft = true`. I tested this and succeeded.