# Windows Forms re-arranging elements in table layout panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I am developing a POS system in .net with windows forms as the GUI. I am facing a very peculiar problem with one window in my app.

(Note : Application is compiled for .net 4 framework and as a windows forms project. I am using a table layout to arrange all the elements in the form).

Given below is the screenshot of the form in Visual Studio.

[image: Window as seen in Visual Studio 2012]

Following is the screenshot in my system (Windows 8 Pro, DELL Full HD monitor).

[image: Window as shown in my system.]

Now I am building the executable files and DLL's and copying them into my dad's system (Windows 7, 1440 X 900 monitor). The application runs successfully but the output is shown below.

[image: Application running in my dad's system]

Two things have changed.

1. The Start-Date and End-Date labels and calendars both have swapped (I tested this functionally too. The start date cannot be later than the end date, if so an error is given. I have checked by this, and the calendars are swapped too.)
2. The format of the Dates being displayed is changed.

NOTE : I have such minor problems in other windows too.

Has anyone ever come across such problem?

Comment: The formatting of the dates is most likely due to the localisation settings (perhaps your father's PC has a preference for short month names instead of numbers - See `Region and Language` in the control panel). As to the calendars... That's far more interesting. I'd suggest either installing VS on that machine and putting a breakpoint on the designer code which positions elements or if that's too much hassle, modify your app to log as much info as you can think of to file, then compare the files between the 2 machines

Comment: Someone also has this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542888/listviews-switch-places?noredirect=1#comment31900377_20542888

Comment: @Basic I have solved the date issue. Just formatted the string myself rather than depending on the system related long date representation.

Comment: Are your controls set to `Dock = Fill`? If this is the case, try to remove all anchors. Test 2 - if use `Fill`, stop using it and set all anchors and use `padding` to clear the border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution.

The windows designer generated code is added the controls in the tablelayoutpanel object in a wrong way.

The windows designer panel is adding controls to the tablelayoutpanel into the same cell.

Ex : Incorrect Code

```
this.tableLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(this.tbInvoice, 0, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(this.label4, 0, 0);
```

Correct Code

```
this.tableLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(this.tbInvoice, 1, 0);
this.tableLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(this.label4, 0, 0);
```

Solution : Re-arrange the controls in the panel by removing them or moving them into a separate table and then moving them back.